# CakePHP URL with HTML Anchor

Tags: cakephp, anchor, cakephp-1.2

I'm using cakePHP 1.2, and wondering how I can handle a URL that dynamically builds the page with a slug, but then links to the appropriate area with an HTML anchor. An example:

www.mysite.com/pageSlug#anchor

I would parse out the slug, which would be used to dynamically build the page. Once built, I would need to jump to the anchor. Any suggestions on how I could do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work if you put anchor name in html code as a `name` attribute for `<a>` element. The browser will then automatically scroll the page to correct position.

```
  <a name="anchor"></a>
```

Just generate your page dynamically and put the above fragment to correct place in your code.

Or am I missing something?

Comment: Just checking if you were awake! 

Ugh, sorry dumb question.